# How to get v-select items inside items?

Tags: select, vuetify.js, v-select

I have a dropdown with v-select

```
    <v-select
      label="Select"
      v-bind:items="companies"
      v-model="e11"
      item-text="employee.name"
      item-value="name"
      max-height="auto"
     >
   </v-select>
```

Data from API like

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {

    return {
      e11: [],
      companies: [
        {
          companyName: 'Google',
          employee: [{
            name: 'Sandra Adams',
            name: 'Ali Connors',
            name: 'Trevor Hansen',
            name: 'Tucker Smith',
          }]
        },
        {
          companyName: 'Facebook',
          employee: [{
            name: 'Sandra Adams',
            name: 'Ali Connors',
            name: 'Trevor Hansen',
            name: 'Tucker Smith',
          }]
        },
        {
          companyName: 'Twitter',
          employee: [{
            name: 'Sandra Adams',
            name: 'Ali Connors',
            name: 'Trevor Hansen',
            name: 'Tucker Smith',
          }]
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

In dropdown item getting [object object] to fixed fixed it? I want to get dropdown list with grouped by company name.

Here is what I want to do
[image]

Here is the codepen link https://codepen.io/yurenlimbu/pen/bGVKGEa?editors=1011

Comment: Are you hoping to show a list of companies with a select list to select an employee from each company? I don't think you can do nested select lists with v-select, you certainly can't with standard HTML selects. You probably need to use v-for to iterate the companies and then pass each company's employees to it's own v-select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a crack at it, as ive also had some issues in the past with vuetify dropdown, i managed to get it to work, you may need to update your current data objects to make the name key unique in the list.

- Added computed property to map companies and employees and inject the employees company so we have one object with the data we need

```js
mappedNames: function() {
      return this.companies.map(function(person) {
        person.employee.forEach(e => e.company = person.companyName)
        return person.employee
        })
    }
```

- Helper function to concat the arrays from the map
- item-value prop update to access entire object, and linked to e11 v-model

[image]

Here is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/mcwalshh/pen/Vwvdvve

EDIT:

I've included the slot for item and selected item, so you can change how the data is displayed inside the select:

```html
  <template v-slot:selection="data">
    {{ data.item.name }} - {{ data.item.company }}
  </template>
```

ref: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/

[image]

Here is the updated codepen:
https://codepen.io/mcwalshh/pen/rNOKqvd

EDIT #2:

Not really sure how to go about adding titles, i suggest reading more vuetify documentation, or perhaps in my example, use the helper in the text-name instead of the items to access companyName. But following from my previous posts, i think the potential way of doing it, is to inject/unshift an object into the employees with:

- `{ name: person.employee.companyName, type: "title" }`

For now in my example i add it straight to the object, then use template v-if's to determine what is a title:
[image]

codepen: https://codepen.io/mcwalshh/pen/NWGzeoK

Now just a matter of targeting parent to match your gif, but im in no way saying this is the best approach, like i said before i had issues with vuetify in the past, so i hope this can help get you by until you work out the best method

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated some issue can you check it.

Comment: No problem, ive added the selected slot in the last codepen link as an example

Comment: @user2389511 Did this answer your original question?